# How to add a full PDF-Page as Background for a PDF-File with iText7

Tags: pdf, itext7

Hello I worked a lot with iText 5 and am very new to iText 7.
I try to figure out how I can use a PDF-File to put it as a Template to my new PDF-Document.

The goal is to generate a Letter, where the Layout is provieded by a static PDF-File lying under the text.
In iText5 i used:

```
  public void onEndPage(PdfWriter pdfwriter, Document document, PdfReader templatePdf) {
            PdfContentByte cb=pdfwriter.getDirectContent(); 
            PdfImportedPage template = pdfWriter.getImportedPage(templatePdf, 1)
            cb.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);
```

I found a tutorial to add Images via PageEventHandler (IEventHandler) and  PdfCanvas aboveCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.newContentStreamAfter(),
                    page.getResources(), pdfDoc);
but the Canvas doesn't accept a PDFPage.

Has anyone a tip how to get this done with iText7?

Tanks a lot for your help!
Yours Toking

Comment: Have a look at http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-6-reusing-existing-pdf-documents.
It includes instructions on how to transform a page into an XObject, which can be added using a Canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Samuel, your hint with the XObject was very helpful.

With the following code I was able to show a PDF-Page as a background.

```
public void handleEvent(Event event) {

    PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.getDocument();
    PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();

    PdfFormXObject pageCopy;
    try {
        pageCopy = bgPage.copyAsFormXObject(pdfDoc);
        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
        canvas.addXObject(pageCopy, 0, 0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```