# How to add a full PdfImportedPage as background for another PdfImportedPage with iTextSharp (or iText 5)

Tags: canvas, background, copy, itext

Post similar to this ([How to add a full PDF-Page as Background for a PDF-File with iText7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752133/how-to-add-a-full-pdf-page-as-background-for-a-pdf-file-with-itext7)) but I need it on **iText 5** (better in **iTextSharp**).

Simplifying: I need a "*page over page*".

Comment: FYI iTextSharp is the old name of iText 5 .NET.

Comment: Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

I've got it! =)

The answer was on topic "*Listing 6.7. Superimposing.java*" of [Chapter 6. Working with existing PDFs](https://livebook.manning.com/book/itext-in-action-second-edition/chapter-6/84)

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOURCE);
Document document = new Document(PageSize.POSTCARD);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));

document.open();

PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();

PdfImportedPage page;

for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++)
{
    page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, i);

    // You can invoke this command "n" times to create overlays, including with pages from other readers
    canvas.addTemplate(page, 1f, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
}

document.close();
```